# fetch soap attribute value google appscript

Tags: web-services, soap, google-apps-script

been playing around with this for a while but cant seem to figure it out. i want to fetch the OverallScore tag but the current code generates a TypeError: Cannot call method "getChildren" of null. need help. below is my current code:

```
 function getDriverScores () {

 var xml = 

   "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" 
    xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
     xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"
      +"<soap:Body>"
      +   "<GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponse 
         xmlns=\"http://www.omnibridge.com/SDKWebServices/AssetData\">"
      +      "<GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResult>"
      +         "<DriverScore>"
      +            "<DriverID>4</DriverID>"
      +            "<OverallScore>99.05209</OverallScore>"
      +            "<Distance>7283.8</Distance>"
      +            "<Duration>683800</Duration>"
      +            "<OverSpeedingScore>100</OverSpeedingScore>"
      +            "<OverRevvingScore>100</OverRevvingScore>"
      +            "<HarshBrakingScore>100</HarshBrakingScore>"
      +            " 
          <OutOfGreenBandDrivingScore>99.64171</OutOfGreenBandDrivingScore>"
      +            "<ExcessiveIdlingScore>94.67081</ExcessiveIdlingScore>"
      +            "<HarshAccelerationScore>100</HarshAccelerationScore>"
      +         "</DriverScore>"
      +      "</GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResult>"
      +   "</GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponse>"
      +"</soap:Body>"
      +"</soap:Envelope>"


      var options =
      {
      "method" : "post",
      "contentType" : "text/xml",
      "payload" : xml,
      muteHttpExceptions:true
      };


     var xmlResult = XmlService.parse(xml).getRootElement();
     var soapNamespace = xmlResult.getNamespace("soap");
     var GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponse = xmlResult.getChild("Body", 
     soapNamespace).getChildren()[0];
     var GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponseNamespace = 
     GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponse.getNamespace();

    var DriverScore = 
    GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponse.getChild("DriverScore", 
    GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponseNamespace).getText();

    Logger.log(DriverScore);

    }
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , works perfect, sorry for late reply.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there are several modifications, so please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve `DriverScore` using `GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponseNamespace.getChildren()[0]`.
- Retrieve `OverallScore` using the retrieved `DriverScore`.

#### Modified script :

```
var xmlResult = XmlService.parse(xml).getRootElement();
var soapNamespace = xmlResult.getNamespace("soap");
var GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponse = xmlResult.getChild("Body", soapNamespace).getChildren()[0];
var GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponseNamespace = GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponse.getChildren()[0];
var GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResult = GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResponseNamespace.getChildren()[0];
var DriverScore = GetDriverScoresInDateRangeResult.getChildren();
DriverScore.forEach(function(e){
  var name = e.getName()
  if (name == "OverallScore") {
    Logger.log("%s, %s", name, e.getText()) // OverallScore, 99.05209
  }
});
```

#### Note :

- `xml` of your script was used for this modified script.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.